# C program which prints the Germain primes in a range received by user

Tags: c

For integers `X` and `Y` received from the user (assuming `X < Y`), write the program that adds all Germain prime numbers in the range of `X` to `Y` to an array and prints the elements in this array on the screen. Germain prime numbers are primes such that the number 2p + 1 is also prime. An additional string will not be used in this question. Otherwise, it will be evaluated as 0.

Sample:

```
Enter X and Y: 2 15
Germain Prime Numbers in the Range: 2-3-5-11
```

I have a question like that. I wrote a program but it was printing some wrong numbers, too. However, it doesn't print anything now

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int x, y, i, j, k, counter = 0, counter2 = 0;

    printf("Please enter x and y values:\n\a");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    for (i = x; i <= y; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }                        
        if (counter == 2) {                                               
            for (k = 1; k <= 2 * i + 1; k++) {
                if ((2 * i + 1) % k == 0) {
                    counter2++;
                } 
                if (counter2 == 2) {
                    printf("%d is a germain prime number", i);
                }
            }
        }
        counter = 0;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Can someone tell me where my mistake is?

**Edit: I shouldn't use the functions created by user**

Comment: Your code includes an `isPrime()` function. Why aren't you using it? Edit: also, `if (2 * i + 1 % k == 0)` should probably be `if ((2 * i + 1) % k == 0)` if you want sensible results.

Comment: `for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {` is true on the first iteration.

Comment: `for (int i = 2; i <= n/i; i++)` runs _much faster_ than `for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)`

Comment: i shouldn't use functions created by user. isPrime added by someone else from site where i shared my code.

Comment: alpermakaveli: Given "in the range of X to Y", what is the allowable range of `X,Y`, the _entire_ `int` range?  Large `int` value may overflow `2 * i + 1` as so need different handling.

Comment: alpermakaveli You have the requirement "adds all Germain prime numbers ... to an array", yet there is no array for them in your code, just output.  Is that a real requirement?

Comment: Aside: Interesting to note these primes named after [Sophie Germain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain).

Comment: An array is obligatory but i haven't created yet. I am just trying to creating correct program struct. I will add an array later

Comment: Finally i have fixed my program but couldn't add those germain primes to an array. I don't know how to create a loop like that as I don't know how many germain primes program will obtain.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is too complicated. The main loop should be simplified. Furthermore, the output is not what the example shows.

Here are the issues:

- the loop `for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)` is a very inefficient inline re-implementation of `isPrime()`.
- the test `if (2 * i + 1 % k == 0)` in the second loop should use parentheses: `if ((2 * i + 1) % k == 0)`
- `counter2` is never reset to `0`. It would be safer to set both `counter` and `counter2` to `0` before their respective loops.
- actually, it would be much better to call `isPrime()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool isPrime(int n) {
    // Corner case
    if (n <= 1)
        return false;
 
    // Check from 2 to square root of n
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int x, y, i, counter = 0;

    printf("Enter X and Y: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d", &x, &y) != 2)
        return 1;

    printf("Germain Prime Numbers in the Range: ");
    for (i = x; i <= y; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i) && isPrime(2 * i + 1)) {
            counter++;
            if (counter > 1)
                putchar('-');
            printf("%d", i);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;   
}
```

If you cannot use function, which is a strange requirement, you can expand the code inside the `main` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, y, counter = 0;

    printf("Enter X and Y: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d", &x, &y) != 2)
        return 1;

    printf("Germain Prime Numbers in the Range: ");
    for (int n = x; n <= y; n++) {
        int isprime = (n >= 2);
        for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                isprime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isprime) {
            int isgermain = 1;
            for (int i = 2, n2 = 2 * n + 1; i <= n2 / i; i++) {
                if (n2 % i == 0) {
                    isgermain = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isgermain) {
                counter++;
                if (counter > 1) {
                    putchar('-');
                }
                printf("%d", n);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;   
}
```

Here is an alternative method using a simplistic sieve of Eratosthenes.  It finds all Sophie Germain primes below 10<sup>9</sup> in less than 30 seconds:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x, y, counter = 0;

    if (argc > 1) {
        x = y = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
        if (argc > 2) {
            y = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Enter X and Y: ");
        if (scanf("%d %d", &x, &y) != 2)
            return 1;
    }
    int max = 2 * y + 1;
    unsigned char *composite = calloc(max + 1, 1);
    if (composite == NULL) {
        printf("out of memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    composite[0] = 1;
    composite[1] = 1;
    for (int p = 2; p * p <= max; p++) {
        if (composite[p])
            continue;
        for (int i = p * p; i <= max; i += p)
            composite[i] = 1;
    }
    for (int p = x; p <= y; p++) {
        if (composite[p] || composite[2 * p + 1])
            continue;
        counter++;
        //printf("%d\n", p);
    }
    free(composite);
    printf("Count of Germain primes between %d and %d: %d\n", x, y, counter);
    printf("approximation for count to %d: 10+1.6*N/log(N)²=%.2f\n",
           y, 10 + 1.6 * y / (log(y) * log(y)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually i shouldn't use a function like isPrime. I think someone changed it from codeshare.

Comment: Finally i have fixed my program but couldn't add those germain primes to an array. I don't know how to create a loop like that as I don't know how many germain primes program will obtain.

Comment: For the number of Sophie Germain primes below **N**, you can use an approximate upper bound **10+1.6*N/log(N)²**. I have a elegant proof for this, but this comment is too exiguous to contain it :)

Answer (score 3):

The "issue" is that you never reset your `counter2` variable and `if (2 * i + 1 % k == 0)` needs parentheses. The real issue is that you have implemented the `isPrime` functionality three times instead of just implementing it once and calling it two times, leading you to be lost in the unnecessary levels of complexity.

Comment: Also hint that `if (2 * i + 1 % k == 0)` should use parentheses.

Comment: Yeah i added that parantheses but i shouldn't use functions created by user. isPrime added by someone else from site where i shared my code

Comment: Whoever told you to not define a function for this is just plain wrong and teaching you bad habits. There are certainly better ways of checking for a germain prime than the algorithm for each number check if n is prime and check if 2n+1 is prime (for instance find all the primes in some range first, then check the 2n+1 condition), but none of those better ways avoid defining a function.

Comment: We haven't seen functions in the lectures, this is why it is banned. I tried to find prime first, then checking primity of 2p+1. However, i lost as a beginner

Comment: @alpermakaveli "We haven't seen functions in the lectures" --> note that `int main()` is a _function_ you are writing.  So you have seen at least one, a special one.

Comment: yes but what i mean was functions created by user

Answer (score 1):

Don't have much time to debug your code. But you can run this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPrime(int n)
{
    // Corner case
    if (n <= 1)
        return false; // Check from 2 to n-1
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

bool isGermanPrime(int n)
{
    return isPrime(n) && isPrime(n*2+1);
}

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    // printf("Please enter x and y values:\n\a");
    // scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    x = 2;
    y = 15;

    for (int i = x; i <= y; i++)
    {
        if (isGermanPrime(i))
            printf("%d ", i);
    }
    return 0;
}

//OUTPUT
2 3 5 11
```

Comment: i shouldn't use functions created by user. isPrime added by someone else from site where i shared my cod

Comment: you'll have to write your own version of isPrime then,  If I was to write one for you that wouls also be unacceptable.

Comment: Yeah that would be definetely unnacaptable. I'm just here to finding where my mistake is and fixing it

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPrime(int n) {
    // Corner case
    if (n <= 1)
        return false;
 
    // Check from 2 to n-1
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
 
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int x, y;

    printf("Please enter x and y values:\n\a");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    for (int p = x; p < y; p++) {
        if (isPrime(p) && isPrime(2 * p + 1)) {
            printf("%d is a germain prime number\n", p);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i shouldn't use functions created by user. isPrime added by someone else from site where i shared my cod

Comment: Okay, sorry I wasn't aware. I assumed you made the function.

Comment: That's my bad, forgot to delete it.

Comment: Is it possible to do without it?

Answer (score 1):

"Write the program that adds all Germain prime numbers in the range of X to Y to an array and prints the elements in this array on the screen." And also "I shouldn't use the functions created by user". Here it is

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main() {

    int x, y, germ, prime, gPrime;
    int n[SIZE], count = 0, i, j;

    scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);

    if( x < 3 ) {

        n[0] = 2;
        ++count;
        x = 3;
    }
    else if( !(x % 2) ) {
        
        ++x;
    }

    for(i = x; i <= y; i += 2) {

        prime = 1;
        gPrime = 1;
    
        for(j = 3; j < i; y += 2) {
        
            if( !(i % j) ) {
            
                prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    
        if( prime ) {
    
            germ = 2 * i + 1;
        
            for(j = 3; j < germ; j += 2) {
            
                if( !(germ % j) ) {
                
                    gPrime = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        
            if( gPrime ) {
            
                n[count] = i;
                ++count;
            }
        } // end outer if
    }

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    
        printf("%d ", n[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: the compiler I use on my phone has a time limit that won't let me see the output. I hope the program works.

Comment: there is no output but it gave me inspiration, thanks

Comment: Oh I thought it was because of a time limit. Anyway you are very welcome